# How to separate data into two csv using a mask based on a specific ID in numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, nan, masking

This is an edited previous question.

I am doing a GIT course Geo Python 2018 in my free time as I am trying to learn python. It is an open course but as I am not a part of that particular university, I have nowhere to turn for help but here.

The input data is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gTWu5l6wiankP4ktfWgHLdw_OqnXX1RoY291HWrIxCM/edit?usp=sharing

First, I read the data:

```
import numpy as np
fp = '../6153237444115dat.csv'
data = np.genfromtxt(fp, skip_header=1, usecols=(0,2,22,27,28), delimiter=',')
```

## adding column variables

```
station = data[:, 0]
date = data[:, 1]
temp = data[:, 2]
temp_max = data[:, 3]
temp_min = data[:, 4]
len(temp)
```

Len is 11694.

I need to do the following in numpy:

1. Create a new mask variable tempmask that is True for all finite temperature values, and False for nan values in the temp variable
2. Remove all rows from the column variables (date, temp, temp_max, temp_min) using the tempmask array

I have been having troubles managing this. So, creation of the tempmask:

```
tempmask = np.isfinite(temp)
```

This makes the mask remove Nan value from temp. Now, I need to use the same tempmask array to remove these specific values from the station, date, temp_max, and temp_min arrays.

```
date = date[tempmask]
temp_max = temp_max[tempmask]
```

Afterward, I need to export two separate csv files. I need to select all rows where the "station" == 29980 using a mask called "kmask" and export that to "kumpula" and other to "Rovaniemi" where the "station" == 29450 using an array mask "rmask".

```
kmask = data[station==29980]
rmask = data[station==28450]
kumpula = kumpula[kmask]
rovaniemi = rovaniemi[rmask]
```

The last part of the code doesn't work which is where I need help.

Comment: Have you really tried the thing you actually wrote (`date = date[tempmask]`)? Because that should work fine---assuming `temp` and  `date` have the same shape.

Comment: I have. I have written it. I always get the same for all columns and I know that one of them has a lot more Nan values but their len is the same at the end. Maybe I am overlooking something.

Comment: don't assign for a second. make your mask. Now check, length of mask, and length of your 3 arrays. if they are all the same, do the operation such as `date[tempmask]` for all 3, but don't assign any of them. As it stands right now, we cannot know your problem because you did not provide a [mcve]. More likely than not, you've overwritten something accidentally or are making a mistake somewhere, because the syntax itself looks correct.

Comment: I think the problem is with what the actual task is. You cannot use the mask obtained from `temp` to remove the `nan`s from `date` unless `temp` and `date` happen to have `nan`s in the exact same positions. But sometimes it is useful to remove stuff from `date` according to a criterion based on `temp`.

Comment: My initial code did the job. Thank you. I thought that I need to remove all Nan from each separately. But this would require a mask per each. Instead, I needed to remove specific Nan rows from the temperature or the temp column.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how I managed if anyone wants to know:

stacking columns and transposing them

```
kumpula = np.vstack((station, date, temp, temp_max, temp_min, celsius))
kumpula = np.transpose(kumpula)
kmask = station==29980
kumpula = kumpula[kmask]
rovaniemi = np.vstack((station, date, temp, temp_max, temp_min, celsius))
rovaniemi = np.transpose(Rovaniemi)
rmask = station==29450
rovaniemi = rovaniemi[rmask]
```